# How to receive the actions made by the user in a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a ListView that displays a list of Contacts. When a contact is clicked, a DialogFragment is created which displays a notice on whether or not to Cancel or Confirm. Based on whether they click Cancel or Confirm I want to change the color of the ListView item.  How can I get the status of the Button click for the dialog.  My code for the dialog:

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        String first = this.getArguments().getString("first");
        String last = this.getArguments().getString("last");
        String phone = this.getArguments().getString("phone");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_contact_dialog, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.new_first);
        tv.setText(first);

        TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.new_phone);
        tv2.setText(phone);

        TextView tv3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.new_last);
        tv3.setText(last);

        builder.setView(view);
        //builder.setTitle("Are you sure?").setMessage("Would you like to add " + name + " as a contact?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // Add the contact

                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Now I want setPositiveButton or setNegativeButton to return a value that I can compare with in my Main Activity or get my ArrayAdapter in the scope of the dialog so that I can make changes to it. Is there any way to relate the `DialogFragment.show()` and the Dialog button that was clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to relate the DialogFragment.show() and the Dialog
>   button that was clicked?

Use an interface to pass that information to the activity which in turn will pass it to the adapter/fragment that has the possibility to do the change:

```
public interface OnSelectionMade {

     int OK = 1000;
     int CANCEL = 2000;
     doChange(int result);
}
```

Make the activity implement this interface and use the `doChange()` callback to do the change in the adapter, either by accessing the adapter directly(if you use a simple `ListView`) or pass it to the fragment holding the `ListView` to do the change:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnSelectionMade {

     @Override
     public void doChange(int result) {
         // the result parameter will be either the OK or CANCEL constants
         // you know now what button was clicked so you can do the change
         ...
     }

}
```

Now you need to wire up the `DialogFragment` to pass the event through `OnSelectionMade` like this:

```
private OnSelectionMade mListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mListener = (OnSelectionMade) activity; // you'd want to implement a cast check here to be safe
}

//then in the onCreateDialog() method
builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       mListener.doChange(OnSelectionMade.OK); // do a null mListener check?
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       mListener.doChange(OnSelectionMade.CANCEL);
                   }
               });
```

You could probably pass a reference to the `DialogFragment` directly to pass the results, but that is not a very good solution long term.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is. In the `Activity` or `Fragment` from where you are instantiating your `DialogFragment`, first declare:

```
public static final int MY_DIALOGFRAGMENT = 123;   /* Any random int values will do. */
public static final int CONTACT_CONFIRM = 124;
public static final int CONTACT_DENY = 125;
```

Instantiate your `DialogFragment` like so:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
myDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, MY_DIALOGFRAGMENT);
myDialogFragment.show(fm, "my_dialog_fragment");
```

In the `onCreateDialog()` method of your `DialogFragment`,

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // Add the contact
                   getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), 
                       MyActivity.CONTACT_CONFIRM, getActivity().getIntent());
                   dismiss();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
                   getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), 
                       MyActivity.CONTACT_DENY, getActivity().getIntent());
                   dismiss();
               }
           });
```

And finally, add the following method to your `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case MY_DIALOGFRAGMENT:

                if (resultCode == CONTACT_CONFIRM) {

                    // Change color of listview item to green

                } else if (resultCode == CONTACT_DENY){

                    // Change color of listview item to red

                }

                break;
        }
}
```

This should work. Try it.

Comment: is `onActivityResult` within the DialogFragment or the MainActivity? Because it seems like it would be in the Dialog class which doesn't have scope access to the ListView

Comment: `onActivityResult()` is in the `Activity` or `Fragment` from where you would be calling the `DialogFragment`. You would certainly have access to the `ListView` from there. The three `public static int` fields should also be placed in the same class where you add `onActivityResult()`. Try it and let me know if you get what you want.