# Android: Dialog fragments and retaining the values selected the first time the dialog is opened when the user opens the dialog for a second time

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

This is (conceptually) what I am looking for and I am finding it difficult to find an answer. Please ask for clarity if needed but I will do my best.

1. A user clicks on a TextView which uses the onClick method (along with listener) to open up a dialog fragment (the dialog fragment is custom dialog with three number pickers side by side).
2. The user picks the numbers they want
3. The user clicks the set button (not cancel button)
4. The user selection is fed back to the calling fragment and put in a TextView field using onActivityResult to pass the values back to the calling fragment.
5. User decides to choose another set of numbers and therefore opens the dialog box again.

How do I make sure the previous dialogFragment selection by the user is what is shown when the dialog is created rather than resetting the value to what it was the first time the dialogFragment was opened?

Do I, for example, need to take the values from the TextView and pass them back to the dialogFragment somehow and set the values in the dialog Fragment?

Any help will be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the `DialogFragment`:

```
DialogFragment myFragment = new DialogFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("number1", a);
args.putInt("number2", b);
args.putInt("number3", c);
myFragment.setArguments(args);
```

And inside the `DialogFragment` class:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
if(args == null){

    // do nothing; this is the first time the user is opening this Dialog
}
else{

    int a = args.getInt("number1");
    int b = args.getInt("number2");
    int c = args.getInt("number3");

    // initialize number pickers

}
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: 'if(args == null)' no way this indicates the dialog is opened for the first time, never. This only means that you've forget to call 'myFragment.setArguments(args)'

Comment: if the text fields are empty, then the `setArguments()` method will not be called; that is self-explanatory. The `if(args == null)` check `must` be made in any case.

Comment: @puzii: was this useful ?

Comment: @Zygotelnit  - apologies I am afraid I do not have enough experience yet!

Comment: @ZygoteInit Since I have now marked this answer as correct can you answer this?

 
I use ExampleDialogFragment df = ExampleDialogFragment.newInstance(1,2,3); to create the dialog fragment. However, I wanted to ask if I was using multiple (different dialog fragments) in one activity/fragment activity then should I send a unique identifier with the bundle or should I use something like startActivity instead in my onClick method?

Comment: @puzii: In any situation, there can be only **ONE** `DialogFragment` in the foreground at a given point of time. When you call the `dismiss()` method, this instance of `DialogFragment` is marked for garbage collection. So when you create a new instance of `DialogFragment`, there is no need to pass any kind of identifier as it will necessarily be `another` instance.

Comment: @puzii: if by *different dialog fragments* you mean separate classes (like say `DatePickerDialogFragment` and `SelectOptionDialogFragment`), then these too will have separate instances (obviously). And besides, as I said earlier, there can be only one `DialogFragment` in the foreground at any given time,with a `unique` instance of its class, so I don't really see why you would have the need to use an identifier for it :)

Comment: @ZygoteInit Thanks. I do mean the second case. However, my current code is the following:

Comment: @ZygoteInit Thanks. I do mean the second case. However, my current code in the custom dialog fragment class is the following:
In builder.setPositiveButton I have an on click event which sends the data back to the calling fragment/activity. It uses this:                getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
where i is my intent bundle parameters to pass back. 
What I am asking is in my activity/fragment I have a method called: public void onActivityResult(......); How is my code supposed to know which dialogfragment's onActivityResults this is?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031167/how-to-receive-the-actions-made-by-the-user-in-a-dialogfragment/24031934#24031934) to a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to pass the parameters back into the new dialog to populate the fields. This can be done by passing the arguments to the dialog as a bundle.

Whether you want to store the three values received from the dialog's previous instance to pass back, or parse the value from the TextView to recreate them, is your choice (I'd probably store the three values myself).

For example:

```
ExampleDialogFragment df = new ExampleDialogFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("value1", 1);
args.putInt("value2", 2);
args.putInt("value3", 3);
df.setArguments(args);
```

Within your dialog's onCreate() method, you can then use something like this to retrieve the values:

```
int value1 = getArguments().getInt("value1", 0);
int value2 = getArguments().getInt("value2", 0);
int value3 = getArguments().getInt("value3", 0);
```

A common mechanism for implementing this is to provide a `newInstance()` static method within your DialogFragment:

```
public static ExampleDialogFragment newInstance(int val1, int val2, int val3) {
    ExampleDialogFragment df = new ExampleDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("value1", val1);
    args.putInt("value2", val2);
    args.putInt("value3", val3);
    df.setArguments(args);
    return df;
}
```

This provides a simple method for creating new instances of your dialog, and hides the internal implementation for argument passing from the client.

To create a dialog fragment, you would then simply use:

```
ExampleDialogFragment df = ExampleDialogFragment.newInstance(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Many thanks! Very useful! My only issue is now parsing the CharSequence that I recive from the TextView back to a integers!

Comment: Could you include the integers in the bundle you pass back to `onActivityResult()`, and store them away to re-use if the dialog is re-opened?

Comment: Hmmm OK. At the moment I am passing back strings (after converting them from integers) in the setPositiveButton of the alertDialog builder. There is no reason why I can't just pass integers - so I can change this. However, as you say, maybe I should store them (or get them from the TextView which is what I am trying to do - after setting the TextView). 
Only issue is how would I store them? Data base?

Comment: I guess that depends on what you're doing with these numbers? If you only need to keep them around for the lifetime of the activity, just store them in member variables, and write them into the saved instance state bundle when your activity stops (and read them back in when it starts).

Comment: Well the numbers are user inputs like latitude, longitude, date and time (custom number pickers) which I will be setting in a form like structure for some use. For the moment I do not want to complicate things and so leaving them in member variables is the answer.

Comment: as you say in your answer above. I use ExampleDialogFragment df = ExampleDialogFragment.newInstance(1,2,3); to create the dialog fragment. However, I wanted to ask if I was using multiple (different dialog fragments) in one activity/fragment activity then should I send a unique identifier with the bundle or should I use something like startActivity instead in my onClick method?